# .Net MAUI Blazor, error while trying to publish for IOS

Tags: ios, publish, maui, maui-blazor

i'm trying to publish my application to IOS but i have an error that i can't fix.

I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0) and i was trying to distribute my app from VisualStudio2022 obviously also having the MAC ( with Xcode updated to the latest version) connected.

I can reproduce all the steps in the guide but the last give me the error.
My app is in net7 but the same error also appears in net6 before the update.

My command in the VS terminal to create the IPA file is:

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-ios -c:Release /p:ServerAddress=192.168.1.117  /p:ServerUser=****** /p:ServerPassword=******* /p:TcpPort=58181  /P:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/*****/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/ /p:RuntimeIdentifier=ios-arm64
```

but everytime console return me this error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\16.2.1024\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(332,3): error IL1031: Invalid assembly action 'partial'. [D:\VSProj\CSys.CTech.Mob
ileApp\CSys.CTech.MobileApp\CSys.CTech.MobileApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-ios]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk\16.2.1024\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.After.targets(110,3): error MSB4044: all'attività "CopyArchiveFiles" non è stato assegnato un va
lore per il parametro obbligatorio "ArchivePath". [D:\VSProj\CSys.CTech.MobileApp\CSys.CTech.MobileApp\CSys.CTech.MobileApp.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-ios]
```

the italian part traslated in eng is << the "CopyArchiveFiles" task has not been assigned a value for the mandatory "ArchivePath" parameter >>

i've tried some things:

- remove the ArchiveOnBuild parameter (or set to false) and the error disappears but obviously the ipa file is not produced
- move the parameters in the .csproj file but nothing change
- add the ArchivePath parameter to command (or to .csproj file) but it give me the same error.
  (does this parameter even exist? I haven't found anything about it)

I hope I have given you all the information to help me.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please make sure you have set the `Archives location` in your `Visual Studio` in windows machine. In VS, select `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> iOS Settings -> Archives location`, usually it should be like `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Archives`.

Additionally, you can directly publish your iOS app via `VS for MAC` in your mac instead of using the `donet publish command`. From the **Build** menu, select `Archive for Publishing`. For more details, you can refer to 
[Build and submit your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos#build-and-submit-your-app);

Reference links:

https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/681#issuecomment-1173703085

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing-to-the-app-store?tabs=macos

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/ipa-output-path

Comment: unfortunately none of these solutions work for me:
archives location is set correctly and also publishing from mac gives me problems.
when I do "Archive for Publishing" it doesn't find the provisioning profile despite having followed the procedure explained.
Could it be that it's because it's for xamarin and not .MAUI ?

Comment: May I know what is your versions of VS 2022 and Xcode? You can also walk through the [Release Your .NET MAUI iOS App to the Apple App Store](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kpZi5xAvpZA) for the detailed steps.

Comment: I already followed this video but came to the same error.
i use:
VS 17.4.5 
XCode 14.2

Comment: @CiccioBoscaiolo Thanks for the update, I'll try to use the publish command to see if it can successfully generate the `IPA` file on my side.